# Find the nearest id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs

```
<div class="maca">
    <input type="hidden" value="1">

    <div onclick="removeInput(nearest input type hidden)">Remove</div>
</div> 

<div class="maca">
    <input type="hidden" value="1">

    <div onclick="removeInput(nearest input type hidden)">Remove</div>
</div>
```

I want to send as a parameter the value of nearest input type hidden of that div that we are clicking on

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure what you mean with nearest but with this you get the input hidden inside the div. By the way you could also put the `element.parentNode.querySelector` into the onclick but personally i like it more to split HTML and JS.

```js
function removeInput(element){
let value = element.parentNode.querySelector("input[type='hidden']").value;
console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<div class="maca">
    <input type="hidden" value="1">

    <div onclick="removeInput(this)">Remove</div>
</div> 

<div class="maca">
    <input type="hidden" value="5">

    <div onclick="removeInput(this)">Remove</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *but personally i like it more to split HTML and JS* Then why are you using inline event handlers?

Comment: Good point. True that was missleading. I meaned i'd like to split the view from the business logic. I see people doing calculations inside the onclick HTML tag... If I use inline event handlers and I think there are situations where it makes sense. I try to keep them short and do the math inside a function. In widely used frameworks like angular or react you also use inline events.

Comment: No, these frameworks don't use inline event listeners - that's a wide-spread misconception. They use declarative event listeners in *templates* (e.g. JSX) which are then **compiled** to use the addEventListener API.

Comment: Angular uses as far as I'm aware of directives that uses under the hood also AddEventlistener but I don't understand your point. Even though they technically don't use the inline events it acts, looks and feels like them or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You can send the event as a parameter to a javascript function and then find the input via the parentNode. This isn't a literal interpretation of your question since faithfully the "nearest" element is rather complex and probably not what you're looking for.

```js
function removeInput(e) {
  const nearestInput = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("input[type='hidden']");
  console.log(nearestInput);
}
```

```html
<div class="maca">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" />

  <div onclick="javascript:removeInput(event)">Remove</div>
</div>

<div class="maca">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" />

  <div onclick="javascript:removeInput(event)">Remove</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha lol i posted the exact same answer cheers mate 

Comment: @ChristianMeyer 

Answer (score 0):

You should not use inline event listeners, which are widely considered bad practice.

Instead, use `addEventListener` to add the click listeners, and find the input (given your markup structure is fix like you've shown) using `previousElementSibling`:

```js
for (const remover of document.querySelectorAll('.remove-input')) {
  remover.addEventListener('click', () => remover.previousElementSibling.remove(), { once: true });
}
```

```html
<div class="maca">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" />

  <div class="remove-input">Remove</div>
</div>

<div class="maca">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" />

  <div class="remove-input">Remove</div>
</div>
```